# Uploading a File from OneDrive to Azure - issues with file content

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-storage, onedrive

We writing an application to move content from an OneDrive account into Azure Storage. We've managed to get this working but ran into memory issues working with big files (> 1GB) and Block Blobs. We've decided that Append Blobs are the best way going forward as that will solve the memory issues.

We're using a RPC call to SharePoint to get the file stream for big files, more info can be found here:
 http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.co.za/2009/09/downloading-content-from-sharepoint-let.html

Using the following code is working fine when writing the file from OneDrive to local storage

```
using (var strOut = System.IO.File.Create("path"))
using (var sr = wReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int read;
    bool isHtmlRemoved = false;
    while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (!isHtmlRemoved)
        {
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            int startPos = result.IndexOf("</html>");
            if (startPos > -1)
            {
                //get the length of the text, '</html>' as well
                startPos += 8;

                strOut.Write(buffer, startPos, read - startPos);

                isHtmlRemoved = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);

        }
    }
}
```

This creates the file with the correct size, but when we try to write it to an append blob in Azure Storage, we are not getting the complete file and in other cases getting bigger files.

```
using (var sr = wReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int read;
    bool isHtmlRemoved = false;
    while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (!isHtmlRemoved)
        {
            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            int startPos = result.IndexOf("</html>");
            if (startPos > -1)
            {
                //get the length of the text, '</html>' as well
                startPos += 8;

                //strOut.Write(buffer, startPos, read - startPos);
                appendBlob.UploadFromByteArray(buffer, startPos, read - startPos);

                isHtmlRemoved = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //strOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            appendBlob.AppendFromByteArray(buffer, 0, read);

        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? Why would we be getting different file sizes?

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In response to **"Why would we be getting different file sizes?":**

1. From the [CloudAppendBlob.appendFromByteArray documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._cloud_append_blob.appendfrombytearray)
   "This API should be used strictly in a single writer scenario
   because the API internally uses the append-offset conditional header
   to avoid duplicate blocks which does not work in a multiple writer
   scenario." If you are indeed using a single writer, you need to
   explicitly set the value of
   [BlobRequestOptions.AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.absorbconditionalerrorsonretry?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) to `true`.
2. You can also check if you are exceeding the 50,000 committed block
   limit. Your block sizes are relatively small, so this is a
   possibility with sufficiently large files (> 16KB * 50,000 = .82
   GB).

In response to **"Is this the correct way of doing it?"**:

1. If you feel you need to use Append Blobs, try using the [CloudAppendBlob.OpenWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._cloud_append_blob.openwritenew#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob__cloud_append_blob_openWriteNew__) method to achieve functionality more similar to your code example for local storage.
2. Block Blobs seem like they might be a more appropriate fit for your scenario. Can you please post the code you were using to upload Block Blobs? You should be able to upload to Block Blobs without running out of memory. You can upload different blocks in parallel to achieve faster throughput. Using Append Blobs to append (relatively) small blocks will result in degradation of sequential read performance, as currently append blocks are not defragmented.

Please let me know if any of these solutions work for you!